# Resolution of geographical image

Tags: image-processing, entity, geographics

There is a simple code to draw a polygon showing Georgia, but resolution is low:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
Polygon[Entity["Country", "Georgia"]]}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to make a high resolution image?

Comment: Try with GeoZoomLevel.