# How to increase the image resolution of a map?

Tags: image, geography

I'd like to obtain higher-resolution geographic maps retrieved from Wolfram geo server, since the standard resolution seems poor.

I tried to increase the "TileSize" parameter, like this:

`GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "Germany"],GeoServer -> {Automatic, "TileSize" -> 1024}]`

but it didn't work. How could that possibly be done?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117679/5478

Comment: `GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "Germany"], GeoZoomLevel -> 8]` will give you plenty of resolution.

Comment: Anyone knows why the post @Kube referenced got closed? And why this is flagged with a close vote? I guess it is off-topic in the sense that it is not WRI who decides the ultimate resolution of the images. But there is certainly a reasonable answer that Kuba tries to make every time and of which I certainly didn't know about.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was asked couple of times so let's keep the reference.

> `GeoZoomLevel` is an option for specifying the resolution at which to render a map.

```
GeoGraphics[
   Entity["City", {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}], 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[10, "Kilometers"], 
   GeoZoomLevel -> #, 
   ImageSize -> 500
] & /@ {10, Automatic, 15}
```

[image]