# Resolution of maps displayed using GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

Is it possible to enhance the default resolution of maps displayed using GeoGraphics? Whilst this function provides a host of options that enable the automation of many mapping tasks, the low resolution of the map image renders it unsuitable for high quality presentation.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120572/5478

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I did look at this Q before posting. And played about with the zoom option. But it doesn't do what I want. Which is the increase resolution of the displayed map (e.g. Printed form to be say 300dpi). The problem is that increasing the zoom level decreases how the map is displayed, including reducing font size for place and street names to a degree that they're unreadable. I sense that what I want isn't possible.